# WPF caliburn Screen and Tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

At the moment I having working tabs and they open and close properly. I'm trying to implement a Close All functionality and a Close all but this tab functionality, was wondering how abouts do I do that? The Tabs are Initialized in my ShellViewModel.

Current TabsView.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                 <StackPanel Name="Panel" Background="#88DDDDDD" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1 0" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action Show($dataContext)]">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" >
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Close All Tabs" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action CloseTabs($this)]"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Close All But This" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action CloseAllButThis]"/>

                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Button Background="Transparent" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [Close($this)]" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.CloseButtonSmall}" Background="#900" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#DDD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#093"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

TabsViewModel.cs

```
private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

public List<IScreen> Items { get; private set; } 

public WorkTabsViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
    _events = events;
    _events.Subscribe(this);
}

public void Close(IScreen tab)
{
    if (tab.DisplayName == "Settings")
    {
        var settingsViewModel = tab as SettingsViewModel;
        if (settingsViewModel != null)
        {
            tab.TryClose();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tab.TryClose();
    }
}

public void Show(IScreen screen)
{
    _events.PublishOnUIThread(new ShowTabEvent(screen));
}

public void Handle(ScreenChangeEvent screenChangeEvent)
{
    Items = screenChangeEvent.Tabs.Where(x => Array.IndexOf(HiddenTabs, x.GetType().Name) < 0).ToList();
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel you can do the following:

```
public class WorkTabsViewModelpublic extends Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    // ....

    void CloseAll() {
        foreach (IScreen tab in Items)
        {
            tab.TryClose();
        }
    }

  // ....
}
```

Then in your view you can add a button that will call that method when clicked

```
<Button x:Name="CloseAll">Close All Tabs</Button>
```

As long as your ViewModel is extends a `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive` (or something similar), this will loop through all of your open tabs and try to close them.